# what does this tag mean in a .php file?

Tags: php

```
<!--?php
```

It's very hard to google this. I understand what `<?php` means, but why `!--` in middle?

It seems to have some bizarre effect that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

This is an HTML comment.

```
<!-- comment -->
```

It's not a valid PHP opening tag and is ignored by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It has no meaning. Looks like someone is commenting it out with a HTML tag.

Comment: yes and that's a very stupid idea, since it will expose the PHP source to the client via HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

some IDE's will let you comment out PHP code  with this statement.  Sublime will for sure.  It is not a way to start a PHP statement though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an HTML comment.

```
 <!-- comment -->
```

if in page the syntax is like below

```
    <!-- <?php ?>-->
```

then that php blog will also not execute

Answer (score 0):

It's literally just a HTML comment.